# Adding user interface using java in eclipse

Tags: java, html

I am extracting specific data about a place.That is if I select a location and choose a particular date it should display all events,exhibitions etc of that particular place. So for that I have to make an user interface. How can I make user interface in eclipse Juno using Java.

Comment: Have you consulted a [tutorial on creating GUIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)?

Comment: Things tagged in Java and Html should be immediately flagged.

Comment: @  PakkuDon .I consulted many. Some of them are suggesting WindowBuilder but I have no idea about it and it seems really difficult. Can you suggest a method

Comment: You can use WindowBuilder for both SWT and Swing user interfaces. There are a ton of tutorials on the [web](http://www.google.com/search?q=WindowBuilder+tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download NetBeans and use that; much easier to develop a GUI for java using this IDE for beginners than using Eclipse. Also familiarize yourself with Swing and its classes (JPanel, etc.) - look through this to learn about swing:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/

And this to familiarize yourself with NetBeans:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/netbeansbasics.html

Comment: @ Trust but currently I am doing my project in Spring Tool Suite. So I have permission to continue using that only